How to enable the internal camera on Acer SPIN (SP514-51N) laptop in GNU/Linux?
Webcam is not working in GNU/Linux (latest POP OS!, properly updated) - anybody made it working? "Not working" means no camera present in the OS.
I am afraid it is not even listed in lsusb, see below :/
In MS Windows (I've got dualboot), it works normally.
Here is some debug info:
spin5 :: ~ » sudo lsmod | grep -iE "video|cam"
videobuf2_vmalloc      20480  0
videobuf2_memops       16384  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
videobuf2_v4l2         36864  0
videobuf2_common       81920  3 videobuf2_vmalloc,videobuf2_v4l2,videobuf2_memops
videodev              356352  4 v4l2_async,v4l2_fwnode,videobuf2_v4l2,ov2740
mc                     81920  5 v4l2_async,videodev,videobuf2_v4l2,videobuf2_common,ov2740
video                  73728  3 acer_wmi,xe,i915
wmi                    28672  3 video,acer_wmi,wmi_bmof
spin5 :: ~ » sudo dmesg | grep -iE "video|cam"
[    0.000000]   AMD AuthenticAMD
[    0.100395] PCI: ECAM [mem 0xc0000000-0xcfffffff] (base 0xc0000000) for domain 0000 [bus 00-ff]
[    0.100395] PCI: not using ECAM ([mem 0xc0000000-0xcfffffff] not reserved)
[    0.224013] PCI: ECAM [mem 0xc0000000-0xcfffffff] (base 0xc0000000) for domain 0000 [bus 00-ff]
[    0.226296] PCI: ECAM [mem 0xc0000000-0xcfffffff] reserved as ACPI motherboard resource
[    0.495588] pci 0000:00:02.0: Video device with shadowed ROM at [mem 0x000c0000-0x000dffff]
[    7.005562] ACPI: video: Video Device [GFX0] (multi-head: yes  rom: no  post: no)
[    7.006168] input: Video Bus as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/LNXVIDEO:00/input/input18
[    8.942344] videodev: Linux video capture interface: v2.00
[ 1755.195885] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
[ 2471.824739] usbcore: deregistering interface driver uvcvideo
spin5 :: ~ » sudo lsusb                       
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 04f3:0c7f Elan Microelectronics Corp. ELAN:Fingerprint
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 8087:0033 Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
spin5 :: ~ »


According to ACER forum, it is a model called "CJFKF28" https://community.acer.com/en/discussion/comment/1302958#Comment_1302958 I will later boot into Windows and provide some info from there.

Here is the info from MS windows device list:
Intel(R) ADL AVStream Camera
DISPLAY\INT3480\4&2DED5861&0&UID144512
VIDEO\VEN_8086&DEV_46A6&SUBSYS_16131025&REV_0C&INT3480
VIDEO\VEN_8086&DEV_46A6&SUBSYS_16131025&INT3480
VIDEO\VEN_8086&DEV_46A6&INT3480
VIDEO\INT3480
INTC#ACPI3480
VIDEO\INT3480
oem81.inf:VIDEO\INT3480,iacamera64.NT,12/30/2021,63.22000.3.6744
_SB.PC00.GFX0.IPUA
ACER FHD User Facing
